# save a string to a core data relationship

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview, relationship

In class Viewcontroller the user saves names to entity Person Attribute name. What I would like to do is when the user hits a name on a tableviewCell in class View controller and is segued to class Two. A name sister is saved under the relationship family. So every time the user segues the name selected on the tableview cell in view did load it will print in the debug section. Joes has a sister. And if Joe was selected 3 times it would print

Joe has a sister
Joe has a sister
Joe has a sister.

If mark is only selected once it would only state Mark has a sister 1 time.

[Image Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yco8.png)

[core Data Entities , Attributes, and Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT0bc.png)

```
   import UIKit;import CoreData


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    
    
    var items : [Person]?
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var theTable: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        theTable.dataSource = self
        theTable.delegate = self
        
        
        fetchPeople()
        
    }
    
    
    
    func fetchPeople(){
        
        do {
            self.items = try context.fetch(Person.fetchRequest())
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.theTable.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            
        }
    }
    @IBAction func ADDSTUFF(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "add person", message: "what is the time", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        alert.addTextField()
        
        
        let submitB = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default){(action) in
            
            let textfield = alert.textFields![0]
            
            let newPerson = Person(context: self.context)
            newPerson.name = textfield.text
            newPerson.age = 20
            
            
            do {
                try self.context.save()
            }
            catch {
                
            }
            
            
            self.fetchPeople()
            
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        alert.addAction(submitB)
        
        self.present(alert,animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        print("espn")
        
        relationshipDemo()
        
    }
    
    
    func relationshipDemo(){
        
        var family = FamilyMembers(context : context)
        
        
        family.name = "ABC Family"
        
        
        var person = Person(context: context)
        
        
        person.name = "Maggie"
        
        person.family = family
        
        
        family.addToPeople(person)
        
        
        try! context.save()
        
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PersonCell", for: indexPath)
        
        
        let person = self.items![indexPath.row]
        
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = person.name
        return cell
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let person = self.items?[indexPath.row].name {
            let vcx = Two()
       //vcx.valueMove = person // Assign the name to valueMove property
            vcx.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext // or .fullScreen
            self.present(vcx, animated: true)
        }
    }

    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") {(action, view, completionHandler) in
            
            let personToRemove = self.items![indexPath.row]
            
            
            self.context.delete(personToRemove)
            
            do {
                try self.context.save()
            }
            
            catch {
    
            }
            
            self.fetchPeople()
            
        }
        
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
    }
}





class Two: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var twoTableA = UITableView()
    var addB = UIButton()
    var data = [String]() // Data source for the table view
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        [twoTableA, addB].forEach {
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            twoTableA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            twoTableA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.40, constant: 0),
            twoTableA.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            twoTableA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            addB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: twoTableA.bottomAnchor),
            addB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.10, constant: 0),
            addB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            addB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        ])
        
        addB.setTitle("Add Johnson", for: .normal)
        addB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addJohnson), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        twoTableA.dataSource = self
        twoTableA.delegate = self
        twoTableA.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
    
    @objc func addJohnson() {
        data.append("Johnson")
        twoTableA.reloadData()
    }
    
    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I have read this twice and I don’t understand what the question/issue is. Or is this more of a request?

Comment: I updated the code just use core data relationship to save to core data every time a user adds a johnson name on the tableview and have it correspond to the person selected in View Controller.